# How do I run separate tasks at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand this is a recurring question but I think my use case is a bit different from the norm:

- On one end, I have a number of tasks running that update the state of a Model object, all running asynchronously with Advanced Python Scheduler
- On the other end, I have a terminal UI framework (asciimatics) that is basically a loop refreshing the screen.

My goal is to have the UI display the state of the Model. How do I do this in python?

Thanks

Comment: run `Advanced Python Scheduler` in separated `Thread` or `multiprocess`. It could use queue or file or database to send information to main thread which runs GUI. And GUI would have to periodically check information in queue, database or file (but it shouldn't wait for data if there is no new data)

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own question. In case anyone stumbles upon a similar problem: the short answer is to use multithreading.

- If you're using APS as well, you can just use the BackgroundScheduler class. It will schedule your tasks in separate threads and won't block the main one.
- If you are using something else for your background tasks, just run them in a separate thread with the `threading` module.